# Can't center js clock properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently started self studying some HTML/CSS/Js, one of my first projects was a clock. I was following a tutorial on how to make it and, in the end, everything seemed to work properly but instead of it being centered, it is too far on the right and I can't seem to find a way to fix the position.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfm8L.png)

```js
var hour = document.getElementById("hour");
var minute = document.getElementById("minute");
var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");

var clock = setInterval(
  function time() {
    var date_now = new Date();
    var hr = date_now.getHours();
    var min = date_now.getMinutes();
    var sec = date_now.getSeconds();

    if (hr < 10) {
      hr = "0" + hr;
    }
    if (min < 10) {
      min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (sec < 10) {
      sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    hour.textContent = hr;
    minute.textContent = min;
    seconds.textContent = sec;


  }, 100
)
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient( 135deg, #8052ec, #d161ff);
}

.clock {
  width: 550px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50% -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clock div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.clock span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clock">
    <div id="hour">00</div>
    <span>:</span>
    <div id="minute">00</div>
    <span>:</span>
    <div id="seconds">00</div>

  </div>
  <!--Script-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma in your `transform` property declaration.

```css
transform: translate(-50% -50%);
```

should be

```css
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Demo:

```js
var hour = document.getElementById("hour");
var minute = document.getElementById("minute");
var seconds = document.getElementById("seconds");

var clock = setInterval(
  function time() {
    var date_now = new Date();
    var hr = date_now.getHours();
    var min = date_now.getMinutes();
    var sec = date_now.getSeconds();

    if (hr < 10) {
      hr = "0" + hr;
    }
    if (min < 10) {
      min = "0" + min;
    }
    if (sec < 10) {
      sec = "0" + sec;
    }

    hour.textContent = hr;
    minute.textContent = min;
    seconds.textContent = sec;


  }, 100
)
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*:after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient( 135deg, #8052ec, #d161ff);
}

.clock {
  width: 550px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.clock div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.clock span {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="clock">
    <div id="hour">00</div>
    <span>:</span>
    <div id="minute">00</div>
    <span>:</span>
    <div id="seconds">00</div>

  </div>
  <!--Script-->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```